# Javascript - Open Window app by javascript catch event dialog is closed or event click any button on dialog

Tags: javascript, windows, dialog, modal-dialog

[image: This is not alert confirm of javascript]

I have a Windows app (a desktop app for Windows 8.1 to demo) and on my website, I run the app by command (JavaScript in Chrome):

```
window.location = "MyAppName:";
```

Then it shows the dialog above (I don't use the confirm dialog but it's still showing). If I click the blue button (Open MyAppName), It will open my app ok, if I click cancel, it just close. Everything ok.

But after running `window.location = "MyAppName:";`, I want to check if my Windows app is opened, or event when the user clicks the blue button or the cancel button on dialog above, or event when that dialog was closed. But I can't find any way to do this.